# code not returning the value when it finds the text vba

Tags: excel, vba

Here's my code. I have bank data with the description in column D and some contain this merchant info for club. i want it to return value 1301 in column E once found. It is not giving an error but isn't returning the value. I am new to VBA. I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
Sub bankmerch()
'
' bankmerch Macro
'1. declare variables
'2. find records that contain club and return value in E

Dim Club As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer 'row counter


Club = "5XXXXXXXXX17877"
finalrow = Sheets("Bank detail").Range("D10000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 4) = ("*" & Club & "*") Then
    Cells(i, 5).Value = "1301"

    End If

Next i
End Sub
```

here is my data example
06/12/2018  442.07      MerchantServices Daily Dep JUN 5XXXXXXXXX17877 816019288*5XXXXXXXXX17877 9000005503 5XXXXXXXXX17877 R00000091004354846212

Comment: Cell() should almost never be used without specifying the sheet and the workbook. Here finalrow is calculated based on the sheet "Bank detail", but the other are related to the current active sheet (that may or may not be "Bank detail".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If Cells(i, 4) Like "*" & Club & "*" Then
```

[MSDN Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/like-operator)

---

If you want to make your code look a bit better, consider this:

```
Sub Bankmerch()

    Dim Club As String
    Dim finalrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bank detail")
        Club = "*5XXXXXXXXX17877*"
        finalrow = .Range("D10000").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To finalrow
            If .Cells(i, 4) Like Club Then
                .Cells(i, 5).Value = "1301"
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

It references the worksheet and the workbook of every cell explicitly and the `*` are added to the string.